# How can I interpret ln(gdp per capita)?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, econometrics, logarithm

How is GDP per capita related to ln(gdp per capita) logically? Yes, I know how a log-lin model is interpreted, but I dont know how to differentiate y and ln(y).

Comment: please specify your data and objective. add tag - self-study.

Answer (score 2):

The log transformation (changing base, i.e., using ln is often just a matter of preference) is frequently used to transform a positive variable which present a multiplicative behavior into another that has a more linear one. For example, let $X$ be some time variable going from 1 to 10. In R:

```
x <- 1:10
```

Now let's have $Y$ be some other variable of interest which, for illustrative purposes, is a function of $X$:

```
y <- exp(x)
```

In a real application, you would not know about this relationship between $Y$ and $X$, but you'd be able to plot their values and guess. In our case, you'd get something like this:

```
plot(x, y, main = "Plot of x and y")
```

[image: plot of x and y]

Now let's say that, for some reason, you don't want to have to deal with this exponential relationship (say, for instance, that you want to fit a simple linear regression model to explain the change in $Y$ per year $X$). Since $Y$ is all positive, one way to simplify your $Y$ data so that it looks more linear is to apply a log transformation. In R:

```
log.y <- log(y)  # the log() function uses base e by default
```

Now, let's look at the plot of this transformed variable:

```
plot(x, log.y, main = "Plot of x and log(y)")
```

[image: plot of x and log.y]

Now you can fit a model of the type $\log(Y) = \alpha + \beta X + \epsilon$. See, from the first plot, how a line of the type $Y = \alpha + \beta X + \epsilon$ would not properly fit the observed data.

The problem with this approach is that now you're dealing with $X$ and $\log(Y)$, not $X$ and $Y$, and talking in terms of the logarithm of a quantity (like log-GDP) will sound unnatural. However, since the logarithm is a one-to-one transformation―meaning you can go back-and-forth between $Y$ and $\log(Y)$ without losing any information―, you should have an easy time detransforming your results from $\log(\mathit{GDP})$ back into GDP for better interpretation.